# JSP can't access mysql driver at eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jsp

I'm new to JSP.
I'm working for database connection at Eclipse IDE.
Java Class File access the MySQL and process. But JSP File give me following error. (*Only a type can be imported. com.mysql.jdbc.Connection resolves to a package*)
[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVyWp.png)

- I added *mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar* to library as external Jar
  and define driver definition.
- I tried many methods described on the internet.
- MySQL server is running.

JSP File:

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8"
    pageEncoding="utf-8"%>
<%@ page import="java.lang.String" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import="com.mysql.jdbc.Connection" %>
<%@ page import="com.mysql.jdbc.Statement" %>

<%
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Connection");
        Connection con = (Connection)DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/cms","root","");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.print(e.getMessage());
    }
%>
```

Sorry for my english is bad.

Comment: Simply remove the imports of com.mysql.jdbc.Connection and Statement

Comment: If you should be loading anything using `Class.forName`, it would be `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`, and why are you casting to driver specific classes, instead of just using `java.sql.Connection`?

Comment: I removed the imports of com.mysql.jdbc.Connection and Statement. Unfortunately, now it is giving this exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Connection

Comment: You don't need to import anything from the `java.lang` package, ever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a **runtime** error, most likely because the jar file is missing *at runtime*. Physically put the jar file in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder instead of adding it as an external jar to the Java Build Path; this is the most reliable way to make sure it is deployed to the server for use at runtime.

If you're using a different tool to launch the server, such as Maven, it probably has a way for you to declare dependencies like this, and is where you should always do that then.

Comment: I put jar files in the WEB-INF/lib directory and added again. It's work. Thank you.